# Call function found in a userform from a separate workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

My work has an Excel tool (we will call it tool B) that uses a userform to prompt the user to input some data.  Upon clicking submit, the userform then calls a function that is found inside the userform code and passes it the inputs from the user.

I have a separate tool (Tool A) that I want to be able to skip over the inputs section of this userform by just directly calling the function and passing it the desired parameters.

Tool B has many different versions that are used and regularly created, but the event of calling this function remains the same.  In case anything changes in that function, I want to be able to just call that and then have it run as intended.

To sum up:

Tool A

-VBA project(I have changed the name here to something else for referencing purposes)

-Module1->contains procedure that calls functionA found in tool B

Tool B

-VBA Project

-UserForm1

```
  -functionA
```

Any Advice?  I have figured out how to run any procedure/function found on the sheets and modules, but I cannot get this to work for the UserForm functions. Oh by the way, this is a public function.

Comment: You can't move the ToolB function to a regular module?  That way you'd have no trouble calling it either from the form or from another project.

Comment: I would if I could, but I regularly grab different versions from a database we have and so I would have to change all of the versions of ToolB on the database.  While that is something that is definitely possible, I have no influence on how the versions of ToolB are edited as I am not one of the management big wigs at my company.